# Multithread e Concorrência de dados + Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Estou reescrevendo um software que serve como ponte de comunicação entre dois serviços. A comunicação é feita via sockets.
O ambiente ele possui alta concorrência de dados, em especial uma lista com os sockets ativos. O software possui alguns problemas por causa que essa concorrência não foi tratada de maneira correta, fazendo com que algumas informações sejam mostradas erradas, ou não sejam entregues em determinada ponta da comunicação.

Como estou reescrevendo, tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o melhor e mais seguro cenário.

Imaginem o seguinte:
Várias threads acessando uma única lista, podendo adicionar, remover e iterar várias vezes no mesmo segundo.

Para resolver esse problema, eu criei a seguinte estrutura:

ServerService (Onde ficaria a lista que seria acessada por todas as threads)

```
@Component
public class ServerService {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> lista = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(new ArrayList<String>());

    public void add(String string, String myThreadName){
            System.out.println(myThreadName+". ADICIONANDO VALOR: "+string);
            lista.add(string);
    }

    public void remove(String string, String myThreadName){
            System.out.println(myThreadName+". REMOVENDO VALOR: "+string);
            lista.remove(string);
    }

    void printAll(String myThreadName){
        synchronized (lista){
            lista.forEach(s -> System.out.println(myThreadName+". ITERANDO VALUE: "+s));
        }
    }

    List<String> getAll(){
       return lista;
    }
}
```

MyRunnable (Onde ficaria a parte de controle dos sockets que adicionariam, removeriam ou 'iterariam' a lista)

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    ServerService serverService;
    String myThreadName;


    @Autowired
    public MyRunnable(ServerService serverService, String myThreadName) {
        this.serverService = serverService;
        this.myThreadName = myThreadName;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            String value = Double.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10));
            serverService.add(value, myThreadName);
            serverService.printAll(myThreadName);
            serverService.remove(value, myThreadName);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DemoApplication (Somente um main para dar inicio)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    ServerService serverService;

    @Autowired
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(serverService, "THREAD 1"));
        taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(serverService, "THREAD 2"));
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, terei o comportamento correto de concorrencia da lista?

Outra dúvida, como eu 'iteraria' a lista dentro da thread, de forma sincronizada, não podendo outra thread adicionar na lista quando outra estiver fazendo a iteração? Esse seria o jeito correto?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        String value = Double.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10));
        serverService.add(value, myThreadName);
        synchronized (serverService.getAll()){ --ALTERAÇÃO AQUI
            serverService.getAll().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        serverService.remove(value, myThreadName);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Caso necessário, eu coloco mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Questões com thread sempre vai depender so cenário!

Porém, é importante conhecer um mecanismo batente util, o **synchronized**. Esse comando faz com que apenas 1 thread seja executada no mesmo tempo.

Com isso, podemos fazer uma lista **synchronized** afim de que a mesma só consiga ser modificada com uma thread por vez.

Use **synchronized** com sabedoria! Não é interessante coloca-la em tudo, pode comprometer seu software e muito.

Uma outra saída, seria criar controle estáticos, como id´s relacionados com thread, lista e operações... Mas essa não é a melhor opção.

Comment: Toda operação na lista, deverá ser sincronizada, por isso, as opções de adicionar, remover, e iterar, deveriam ser sincronizadas. Você comentou do syncronized, o `CopyOnWriteArrayList` faz esse trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

-**As operações que modificam o conteudo da lista têm de ser synchronized.** Quando se coloca um método synchronized apenas permite que uma thread execute de cada vez. Daí ser importante que o seu codigo não seja todo synchronized porque seria sempre só uma thread a percorrer o codigo de cada vez. (Use/Veja a implementação da **blocking queue**)

-Porquê?
Por exemplo, quando se retira algo da lista e decrementa-se o tamanho da lista (i--), vamos supor que são precisas 3 sub-ações para decrementar o tamanho da lista (buscar o valor do i, decrementa-lo e atualizar o seu valor), caso duas threads façam esta ação ao mesmo tempo pode ser que enquanto uma está a retirar da lista, a outra ja fez as duas primeiras sub-ações e ainda não atualizou o novo valor do i e só vai atualizar após a outra buscar o valor do i o que não era correto (a thread ia buscar um valor desatualizado).